# Navigate away from react-router?

Tags: javascript, spring, react-router

My React app is currently nested inside of a Spring app, which means my routing is mixed. For example, `/route/1` is handled by `react-router`, but `/route/1/details` is *not*.

I have a component which receives a destination URL from the server as props. Some destinations are inside the router and others are outside. In an attempt to safely use `<Link />` in place of `<a />`, I have the following catch-all route handler:

```
{
  path: '*',
  onEnter({location}) {
    window.location.href = location.pathname;
  }
}
```

This works to get me out of `react-router` and back to Spring; however, it breaks the back button. Pressing back from here cycles through the URL history without ever reloading the page. (The history is all routes handled by `react-router`.)

Am I missing something obvious here? I think I want `back` to force a reload, but I'm not sure how. (I see that this is sort of an XY-problem; I'm open to suggestions for different ways of approaching the problem.)

I recognize this is not an ideal solution; it is one step in a migration plan.

Comment: Does using an anchor element break anything? The `<Link>` component is only meant to be used for internal navigation.

Comment: @PaulS yes; standard `a` tags will route through Spring, meaning my entire page reloads instead of just transitioning in React.

Comment: Is that not what you want for non-`react-router` routes (like `/route/1/details`)?

Comment: @PaulS my component receives the destination as a prop; some are inside the router, some are outside the router. I will update my question to make that clearer. I want to route internally when possible and only go back to the server when I need to.